# Find an example for $\left\langle H, C_{G}(H)\right\rangle$ is not abelian.

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, abelian-groups

Prove that if $H$ is an abelian subgroup of a group $G$ then $\langle H, Z(G)\rangle$ is abelian. Give an explicit example of an abelian subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ such that $\left\langle H, C_{G}(H)\right\rangle$ is not abelian.

The proof of the first line is ready.

However I wonder what is the conterexample that makes $\left\langle H, C_{G}(H)\right\rangle$ non-abelian.

Comment: Hint: Things that commute with $H$ need not commute with each other.

Comment: Here is an example: $G=C_2\times S_3$, $H=C_2$,

Comment: @kabenyuk you can make an example of half the size (both group and subgroup).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin
Are you suggesting we take $G=S_3$, $H=\{e\}$? That's witty! I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @lizzz You can describe the subgroup generated by $H$ and $Z(G)$, right?

Comment: That's great, I'll try it. Thanks!